# Finding the form of an Infinitesimal Lorentz matrix

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lie-algebra, calculus, approximations

In the context of Lie groups, when looking for the form of the Lorentz generators we expand a general Lorentz matrix using some infinitesimal parameter $\epsilon$ such that $\Lambda = \mathbb{1} + \epsilon X$.

The form of $X$ is restricted by the metric preserving equation ie $\Lambda^T \eta \Lambda = \eta$. We obtain that $$\mathbb{1} + \epsilon ( X^T + X ) + \epsilon^2 X^TX= \mathbb{1}.$$ To leading over we want to infinitseimal contriburion to vanish so we have $X=-X^T$.

The bit I don't understand is that once we impose this condition the leading infinitesimal contribution is now $\epsilon^2 X^TX$. Why do we not require $X^TX=0$?

Comment: Because it is a second order change, $\propto\epsilon^2$, just because it is now the first non-vanishing term doesn't mean it's size increases.

Comment: Divide by $\epsilon$ and then let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: If you want to find the conditions at order $\epsilon^2$, you have to expand $\Lambda$ to order $\epsilon^2$, to wit, $\Lambda=1+\epsilon X+\frac12\epsilon^2X^2$. Once you do this, you get $X^t\eta+\eta X=0$ to first order and $\frac12(X^t)^2\eta+X^t\eta X+\frac12\eta X^2=0$ to second order. The last equation is trivially satisfied if the first one is. More generally, only the first order equation carries information. The higher orders are all automatically satisfied if the first order is, which is the magic of Lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Lambda=1+\epsilon X$, with $X$ a generator, is only correct up to order $\epsilon$. You need a slightly more rigorous definition of the Lorentz generators to completely justify this. Suppose $q(t)$ is a smooth path through the space of Lorentz transformations that passes through $\mathbb{1}$. Specifically, for each $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $q(t)$ is a Lorentz transformation, and $q(0)=\mathbb{1}$. Then $q'(0)$ is a tangent vector to the identity $\mathbb{1}$. These tangent vectors are essentially "infinitesimal" Lorentz transformations, and any generator can be written in the form $q'(0)$ for some function $q$.

I'm going to use explicit index notation to avoid ambiguities (statements like $\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda=\eta$ or $X=-X^T$ depend on whether indices are up or down). Now, since $q(t)$ is a Lorentz transformation, we know that
$$\eta_{\mu\nu} \big[q(t)\big]^{\mu\rho}\big[q(t)\big]^{\nu\sigma}=\eta^{\rho\sigma}$$
$$\implies 0=\frac{d}{dt}\big(\eta_{\mu\nu} q^{\mu\rho}q^{\nu\sigma}\big)=\eta_{\mu\nu}q^{\nu\sigma}\frac{d}{dt}\big(q^{\mu\rho}\big)+\eta_{\mu\nu} q^{\mu\rho} \frac{d}{dt}\big(q^{\nu\sigma}\big).$$
For $t=0$, using $q(0)=1$, we get
$$0=\eta_{\mu\nu}\delta^{\nu\sigma}\frac{d}{dt}\big(q^{\mu\rho}\big)|_{t=0}+\eta_{\mu\nu} \delta^{\mu\rho} \frac{d}{dt}\big(q^{\nu\sigma}\big)|_{t=0}={\delta_\mu}^\sigma\frac{d}{dt}\big(q^{\mu\rho}\big)|_{t=0}+{\delta_\nu}^\rho \frac{d}{dt}\big(q^{\nu\sigma}\big)|_{t=0}$$
$$=\frac{d}{dt}\big(q^{\sigma\rho}\big)|_{t=0}+\frac{d}{dt}\big(q^{\rho\sigma}\big)|_{t=0}.$$
Let $X^{\mu\nu}=\frac{d}{dt}\big(q^{\mu\nu}\big)|_{t=0}$. Then $X$ is a tangent vector to the identity, and a generator of the Lorentz group by definition. We have shown
$$X^{\sigma\rho}=-X^{\rho\sigma}.$$

**Edit** Alternatively, if you're willing to accept that $e^{\epsilon X}$ is a Lorentz transformation for any generator $X$, then you can expand
$$e^{\epsilon X}=1+\epsilon X+\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}X^2+\frac{\epsilon^3}{3!}X^3+...$$
and solve $(e^{\epsilon X})^T \eta e^{\epsilon X}=\eta$ and match the coefficients of $\epsilon^n$ on each side (all of the equations give the same requirement: $X=-X^T$).

Comment: $q^t\eta+\eta q=0$ does not imply that $q^t+q=0$.

Comment: This is the problem with using index-free notation. Explicitly, $\eta_{\mu\sigma}{X^\mu}_\rho+\eta_{\rho\nu}{X^\nu}_\sigma=X_{\sigma\rho}+X_{\rho\sigma}=0$, so $X_{\rho\sigma}=-(X_{\rho\sigma})^T$. Furthermore, 
$({X^\rho}_\sigma)^T=(\eta^{\rho\mu}X_{\mu\sigma})^T=\eta^{\mu\rho}X_{\sigma\mu}=-\eta^{\mu\rho}X_{\mu\sigma}=-{X^\rho}_\sigma$.

Comment: We agree on the result, but we disagree on the notation. We write either $X\eta+\eta X^t=0$ or $\tilde X+\tilde X^t=0$, with $\tilde X:=X\eta$. But we cannot write both $X\eta+\eta X^t=0$ and $X+X^t=0$. In these equations, $X$ represents a different matrix, so we should use a different symbol. Or the explicit index notation that you write in the comment, which is indeed correct.

Comment: You're right. I updated my post to use explicit index notation.